# Any followup to "What questions should attendees of ESRI UC be asking?

Tags: discussion

https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/518/what-questions-should-attendees-of-the-esri-uc-be-asking
Contained a lot of good questions, but I haven't seen any commentary from those that may have attended.  Did anyone go and were any of the questions asked?

Comment: This were a blog entry would be good on GISse. Twitter was a good source when the event was happening - but a round up would be good to hear about. Most interested in 10.1 and read/write to postgis without ArcSDE.

Answer (score 3):

Looking into setting up a GIS Blog

We are required to:

1. Raise the idea on the child meta. A community blog needs the
   involvement of community members.
2. Define the scope and purpose of the blog. Is the blog about the
   site? Is it about the site’s topic? Is it about the industry around
   the topic? Keep in mind the audience of your community and their
   interests. Another generic blog about  may not be all that
   interesting.
3. Recruit contributors. Who will write entries for the blog? Starting
   a blog is a bit like going through the buffet line. Be realistic –
   don’t let your eyes be bigger than your stomach. Think seriously
   about if and how often you will be able to contribute a blog post,
   including research/prep time.
4. Plan a schedule. Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a
   rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a
   week, posted Mondays? Will there be  posts on Tuesdays and 
   posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but
   I would say at least one post a week.

http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/

Comment: I have put in a request for gisSE to have an official blog - requested **blog.gis.stackexchange.com** waiting response from stack-exchange employees. Will update with a new meta post if positive.

Answer (score 1):

I answered as many of the questions as I could as a comment to the question asked (technically, I added the comment on the *answer* [which really was a question] to the initially asked "What questions should...." Okay, now I can see why this might have been a bit confusing).

Perhaps someone could migrate the questions and their respective answers from that question to chat. That would at least provide a "transcript" of the Q&As. (On second thought, no, that'd be worse than just leaving them here, one, since most people wouldn't know to go to chat to look for those answers and, two, sifting through the chat log to find those answers isn't really conducive to getting questions answered.)

There's just really no good place to put them right now. If we had the GIS blog, it'd be a cinch since the Qs and As could all be added on one "page" and it could be updated as other questions are answered over time.